# Access token not getting saved in database after integrating with Identity Server EF

Tags: identityserver4

I am implementing EF for Identity framework 4 so that i can store tokens in database. My question is, does it store code, Access token and Refresh token all in database (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/ef.html). 
After i implemented code from the document link, that i pasted above, i am getting refresh token data in database but not access token. Also when i try to get a new access token from refresh token, i get new refresh token as well for which i dont see a new entry in database (PersistedGrants) table.

```
    StartUp:
                services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(filename: "key.rsa")
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
                })
                .AddConfigurationStoreCache()

    Client: 
                ClientId =  "testclient",
                ClientName = "testclient",
                ClientSecrets = { "password" },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                RequireConsent = false,

                RedirectUris = { "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc"},

                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/signout-callback-oidc" },

                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/FrontChannelLogout",
                //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/signout-callback-oidc",

                 AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "OpenId",
                    "Profile",
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
```

Comment: JWT based access tokens will not be stored in the database.  Are you using reference access tokens?

Comment: Richard: Thanks for insight. In the client configuration i havent specified any type for access token, so i assume that default behavior is JWT token? I will try and post here.
Do you know anything about 2nd part of my question 
"Also when i try to get a new access token from refresh token, i get new refresh token as well for which i dont see a new entry in database (PersistedGrants) table."

Comment: I used the following setting in client configuration : 
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html?highlight=Operational%20data)
Still i am not seeing any access token entry in database, am i missing something?